# Proper choice of CSS packages in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've assigned myself the project of building a web app with PHP and SQL. My programming experience is long (starting in 1980) but not deep and most of it is in R over the last 10 years. I can read an HTML document, and hack it, but building one is not something I have yet mastered. I've gotten advice to use CSS::bootstrap and am looking at the homepage at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ . Given that I intend to build a server app, I'm guessing I do not want the minified version, and the Sass-compiled version looks to require a level of infrastructure that I don't have, so is the middle version built on a Mac going to be appropriate? I don't see much that is Mac-specific, but it's just a Unix box, right?

Comment: css/javascript is client-side only, so it doesn't even matter what your platform is. If you don't intend to modify bootstrap too much, the minified version is fine.

Comment: I guess it's also worth pointing out the middle version will require a less compiler, which you probably don't want

Comment: So there seems to be agreement that the minified version is the place to start.

Comment: yeah, exactly. Mostly less/sass would be used to say, change all the default colors or spacing across all the css classes on the page, or to implement class attribute inheritance, but since you're just starting out you can override specific classes that you use with your own css, so the minified version is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minified version is no different than the the regular css other than the fact that all of the code is more compact as to save space and make the file size smaller.  You won't be using this for the changes you'll be making to your css anyway.  You'll actually want to build your own css style sheet in order to customize the app your building.  The css from bootstrap is just the basis for the proper structural output of your app on different devices.  When it comes to HTML and CSS there is nothing that is specific to Macs Windows or Linux based systems.  The only specifics are related to browser compatability.